# how to make reset button on Metro UI bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, metro.js, metro-ui-css

i have some problem on my php code..

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="proses.php">
    <div class="input-control text area">
        <textarea name="ipt1" type="textarea"><?php echo $data['data'];?></textarea>
    </div>
    <input name="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <input name="clear-btn" type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').clear();"/>
</form>
```

the result is nothing happened when i click the "Clear" button, and "ipt" field is not cleared,
i need to help, if anyone know, please tell me.

Comment: Do you have this inside the `<form>`?

Comment: yes i have ...

<form id="ipt" method="post" action="edit/proses/ip.php">
.....
    </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type='reset'` button will reset all form values, but your problem is you have some default values coming from PHP. You can do the following:

```
<input name="clear-btn" type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="document.getElementsByName('ipt1')[0].innerHTML=''"/>
```

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) here is used to access the content inside `textarea`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G6pdw/)**